# ESP8266 error: espcomm_upload_mem failed while uploading sketch

Tags: arduino, esp8266

First of all, I would like to apologize for posting this error once again to this community. However, I have been studying articles for last many days to resolve this error. Unfortunately, I did not get any solution which could resolve my problem.

Below is the error which I get when uploading a sketch (even the example sketch):

**warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed**

Here are the connections:
Vcc - 3.3V
RST - 3.3v
CH_PD - 3.3v
Tx - Rx
Rx - Tx
GPIO0 - GND
GND - GND

I tried various combinations like Tx to Tx, Rx to Rx, pulling off GPIO0. Pulling off reset and ch_pd. Supplying external power source, supplying power directly from Arduino using 3.3V. Supplying power from Arduino 5V using an LD33V regulator. I have even tried uploading the code using USB to TTL. But every time I get exactly the same error.

Comment: This is not a coding question. You'd be better off asking it on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ I think...

Comment: You need to do a better job of explaining what you're attempting to accomplish. You list "connections" but don't say what the ESP8266 is connected to. This is a useful reference for this sort of error: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/faq/a01-espcomm_sync-failed.rst. If it solves your problem then please answer your question to help others who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to force these things into programming mode.
Hold down the RESET and FLASH buttons right before deploying and that error should go away.